# How do I fix TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, firebase-authentication

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import app from "../../config/firebase";


// Define the initial state
const initialState = {
  value: null, // Use null to indicate that the user is not signed up yet
};

// Define your slice
const signupSlice = createSlice({
  name: "signup",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    userSignup: (state, action) => {
      const email = action.payload[0];
      const password = action.payload[1];
      const auth = getAuth(app);

      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          const user = userCredential.user;
          if (user) {
            // Create a new state object with updated user data
            console.log(user);
            state.value +=user
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          // Handle errors, but no need to return state in case of error
        })
        
    },
  },

});

// Extract the action and reducer
export const { userSignup } = signupSlice.actions;
export default signupSlice.reducer;
```

I need help fixing this get proxy error:

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked at signupSlice.js:25:1

This only happens when I try to update the state with user you see there. I want to update this state so I can pull this anywhere in the app. How do I get rid of this proxy error?